# using PHP to pull data with curl and -XGET

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use the Twilio api, that is here: https://www.twilio.com/lookup

it says that if I call this:

```
curl -XGET "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/(405)%20555-1212?Type=carrier&Type=caller-name" -u "{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}"
```

it will respond with data like this:

```
{
 "country_code": "US",
 "phone_number": "+14055551212",
 "national_format": "(405) 555-1212",
 "url": "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumber/+14055551212",
 "caller_name": {
    "caller_name": null,
    "caller_type": null,
    "error_code": null,
 },    "carrier": {
    "type": "mobile",
    "error_code": null,
    "mobile_network_code": null,
    "mobile_country_code": "310",
    "name": null
 }
}
```

so in PHP how do I call that as a variable?

I tried this:

```
$res = curl -XGET "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/(405)%20555-1212?Type=carrier&Type=caller-name" -u "{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}";
```

But I get errors.

I tried to create a curl function like this:

```
function url_get_contents($_turl) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_turl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($output === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

then call it like these:

```
$res = url_get_contents("https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/4055551212?Type=carrier&Type=caller-name -u AccountSID:AccountAuth");
```

and

```
$res = url_get_contents("https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/4055551212?Type=carrier&Type=caller-name");
```

but the first one does not work. the second one works but it says I did not pass a valid sid and auth...

So, is there a way to make this work without tons and tons of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to do this recently. It looks like you are trying to pass the Curl authentication parameters incorrectly. Give this function a try:

```
function lookup($number){

    // Twilio Account Info
    $acct_sid = "xxxxx";
    $auth_token = "yyyyy";

    // Fetch the Lookup data
    $curl = curl_init("https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/".$number);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $acct_sid.":".$auth_token);
    $response_data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Handle the Data
    $lookup_data_array = json_decode($response_data,true); // Convert to array
    print_r($lookup_data_array);die();

}
```

Then you just pass the number you want to lookup like this:

```
$this->lookup("650-319-8930");
```

You should then get a response like this:

```
Array
(
    [caller_name] => Array
        (
            [caller_name] => CLOUDFLARE, INC
            [caller_type] => BUSINESS
            [error_code] => 
        )

    [country_code] => US
    [phone_number] => +16503198930
    [national_format] => (650) 319-8930
    [carrier] => Array
        (
            [mobile_country_code] => 
            [mobile_network_code] => 
            [name] => Proximiti Mobility 2
            [type] => voip
            [error_code] => 
        )

    [url] => https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+16503198930?Type=carrier&Type=caller-name
)
```

Good Luck!